# Flask Uploads - TypeError: save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'

Tags: python-2.7, flask, flask-wtforms, flask-uploads

I'm trying to upload a file with Flask and write a renamed file at completion.  Per the [Flask-Uploads docs](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Uploads/), save() has a name parameter for this purpose.  I receive TypeError: save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name' when using the code below.  If I omit the name portion of the save function, file.save(os.path.join('/path/to/uploads', filename)), everything works as intended.

My intent is to prepend the cust value from the wtform that the filefield is located at as the filename that is written, custvalue_filename.extension, as evidenced by my attempt with name=renfn.

views.py

```
def fc_upload():
    form = InvFcUploadForm(next=request.args.get('next'))
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate_on_submit():
        file = request.files['file']
        if file:
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            renfn = str(form.cust.data) + '_' + filename + '.'
            file.save(os.path.join('/path/to/uploads',
                filename), name=renfn)
            flash('File uploaded.', 'success')
    return render_template('inventory/fc_upload.html', form=form)
```

I'm just learning python and Flask, so I fully suspect I'm missing something obvious.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Per Flask's API documentation, the content of the `files` attribute of the `request` object is a `MultiDict` object whose values hold a `FileStorage` object.  As you can see from the Werkzeug documentation linked below, the `save()` method of these objects do not accept a `name` keyword parameter.

http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.9/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage

I haven't tested it myself, but to do what you want in this case you may want to try modifying the `filename` attribute of the `FileStorage` object.  Alternately, open a file object manually with the name mangled in the fashion you wish and pass it in as the first parameter to the `save()` method (just remember to call `close()` on the file object afterwards if you do so).

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and I resolved it by using something like

```
file = request.files['file']
file.filename = "abc.txt"  #some custom file name that you want
file.save("Uploads/"+file.filename)
```